# What are the risks of loading textures from images at runtime in XNA?

Tags: xna, runtime, textures

What is there to know about (apart from only being able to do that on PC) loading textures from images at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

I've been exclusively loading my textures from streams as well, and the only "danger" that I can come up with is Premultiplied Alphas. You'll either need to process each texture as you load it, or render with premultiplied alphas disabled. Shawn Hargreaves wrote a [great blog article on this subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/08/premultiplied-alpha-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx). In the comments, he mentions:

> If you don't go through our Content Pipeline, you have to handle the format conversion yourself, or just not use premultiplied alpha

So initializing your sprite batch(es) with [BlendState.NonPremultiplied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.blendstate.nonpremultiplied.aspx) should work.

In my game, I have processed each texture when I load it.

**EDIT:** Here's my method:

```
private static void PreMultiplyAlphas(Texture2D ret)
{
    var data = new Byte4[ret.Width * ret.Height];
    ret.GetData(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        var vec = data[i].ToVector4();
        var alpha = vec.W / 255.0f;
        var a = (Int32)(vec.W);
        var r = (Int32)(alpha * vec.X);
        var g = (Int32)(alpha * vec.Y);
        var b = (Int32)(alpha * vec.Z);
        data[i].PackedValue = (UInt32)((a << 24) + (b << 16) + (g << 8) + r);
    }
    ret.SetData(data);
}
```

As you can see, all it does is multiply the color channels by the alpha, then stuff it back into the texture. Without this, your sprites will likely appear brighter/darker? than they should. (disclaimer: I didn't write the method above, a friend of mine did)

Comment: I really don't get that premultiplied alpha problem, I mean I never saw anything awkward in my project. Could you post a picture that shows what it is?

Comment: It could be worth reading some more about premultiplied alphas from a few places like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending) and more on [Shawn's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/10/premultiplied-alpha-in-xna-game-studio.aspx). From what I've gathered, if you're using alphas (RGBA), your colours will be off if you do not premultiply your alphas, or render using the NonPremultiplied blendstate. It's pretty straight forward to fix. When I get home, I'll paste my code here.

Comment: @user1306322, here's a great question that deals with an issue resulting from not using premultiplied alphas: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/why-do-my-sprites-have-a-dark-shadow-line-frame-surrounding-the-texture