# Texture2D render image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, render-to-texture

What is the fastest possible way to fill a Texture2D with image?

Under /Images/image.png I have the desired image.

My existing code just fills the texture with white color. How can I make it render the image?

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, this.Width, this.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
Color[] colors = new Color[this.Width * this.Height];
for (int j = 0; j < colors.Length; j++)
    colors[j] = color;
texture.SetData(colors);
```

Maybe I do it the wrong way but what is the easiest/fastest way to dynamicly display image on the screen?

### Update

I changed my code to use ContentManager.

```
ContentManager contentManager = (Application.Current as App).Content;
Texture2D texture = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("/Images/block.png");

contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/block.png")
```

throws "File not found".

```
contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(@"/Images/block.png")
```

throws "Error loading "\Images\block.png". Cannot open file."

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but isn't the normal XNA way of doing this something like: `Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("images/image.png");`?

Comment: How do I access the Content? When I type "Content" I just get "ContentControl", "ContentPresenter", "ContentChangedEventArgs" etc. but no "Content"!

Comment: Make sure your project has `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;` and `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;` And you should put those lines in `LoadContent()` method.

Comment: When I try to load the image I get the exception "Error loading "\Images\block.png". Cannot open file."

Comment: The path starts in your game's .exe file. Make sure the Images folder is there. Also try removing the first "\" sign from the path before "Images".

Comment: To your update: you shouldn't normally have to create a content manager manually, you should already have it available in a new XNA project. Try creating a new XNA solution and use `Content` as described.

Comment: The Images folder is in the same location as all my .cs classes. When I removed the first "/" the exception was "Cannot find file" so it looks like this is not causing the problem.\

Comment: This is because you missed the "@" sign before the string. You either write it like so: `@"Images\image.png"` or `"Images\\image.png"`. Also your Images folder must be in the `bin` folder, where the compiled binaries are, not in your source files folder.

Comment: contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/block.png") throws "File not found". contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(@"/Images/block.png") throws "Error loading "\Images\block.png". Cannot open file."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21037/discussion-between-user197483-and-user1306322)

Comment: I strongly recommend you follow the XNA tutorial from Microsoft http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

Answer (score 2):

The easiest possible way is to just rely on the content pipeline as suggested.

When you create your XNA project, you should have two projects: MyGame, and MyGame (Content).
Right click on the Content and select "Add Files".  This will allow you to import images that can easily be pathed and get compiled into a .xnb format.  I believe this is intended to accelerate things a little.

Once you've done that, you need a `ContentManager` object. Ideally you will use `Content` from your game class - which is already set up for you. But you can create one with:

```
ContentMananger content = new ContentManager(Services, "Content");
```

Where `Services` is from your game class (or an `IServiceProvider` with a `GraphicsDeviceService`). The second argument is the root directory of your content folder.

Which will allow you to load arbitrary data formats from the content pipeline via:

```
content.Load<Texture2D>("myTexture");
```

(Note that you do not include the file extension.)

For ease, I suggest you make an "Images" folder in the Content project as you will have a large number of resources eventually and it makes it easier to organize.  You could also have an SFX, Music, XML, etc, folders to handle all the data types your game will need.

So you'd do:

```
Texture2D myTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>("images/myTexture");
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
```

(Note that these objects obviously need to be visible at the class scope).  This would occur in your Initialization code for loading files.

After that, you would use the Draw method to actually draw the sprite

```
public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
   spriteBatch.Begin();
   spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Vector2(320, 240), Color.White);
   spriteBatch.End();
}
```

And your sprite is magically drawn.

What you're doing is essentially programmatically defining an image and then drawing it.  While they has applications at points, probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Wonderfull answer. Although the code throws an error Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException was unhandled
  Message=Error loading "images\image.png". File not found.

Comment: also ContentMananger does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @user197483 I fixed up the bugs in this answer. Try it again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load an image at runtime, you can use this piece of code:

```
string file = @"Content/images/1.png"; // @ sign is to treat '/' as a character, not a control symbol
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
Texture2D texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, fs);
fs.Dispose();
```

…And then just use `texture` like so:

```
spritebatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(123, 456), Color.White);
```

To use `FileStream` you may need to add `using System.IO;` in your game class.

This method is not considered standard practice, it may lead to problems with alpha channel, and to fix them you'll need to use a different alpha blending state. You can find more on that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078206/what-are-the-risks-of-loading-textures-from-images-at-runtime-in-xna).

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run the code: Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)

Comment: Make sure you have your paths set right, and the file is not open in any editor or viewer.

Comment: What method do you recommend?

Comment: If you're not sure, just use the default method recommended by the creators of XNA — content pipeline, as Simon Whitehead commented to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the [content pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203887.aspx) to add the texture, use [`Texture2D.FromStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434103.aspx):

```
FileInfo imageFile = new FileInfo("Images\\image.png");
Texture2D image = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, imageFile.OpenRead());
```

If you're loading a lot of textures, you might want to **dispose them when you don't need them anymore**.